# Relation between roots of a function and roots of its derivative, IVP

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I am troubled with this question of my book:

[image]

I do know that **f (a) = f '(a) = 0** if the multiplicity of root 'a' is greater than 2 but how that fact is exploited here or is there something more that I need to know to solve this problem.

Comment: the first three sentences prove that there are at least two real roots. that is all you need to answer the question. i have no idea why and where the authors is going after that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know for sure where all your difficulties arise, so I will concentrate on the highlighted part of the OP, and related matters.

The author has shown that if there are only real roots, then these roots must be distinct, say $a\lt b\lt c\lt d$.

Between any two roots of $f(x)$, there is a root of $f'(x)$ (Mean Value Theorem, really a special case of it called  Rolle's Theorem). So if there are $4$ distinct real roots, there is a root of $f'(x)$ between $a$ and $b$, also one between $b$ and $c$, also one between $c$ and $d$. So if $f(x)$ had only real roots, then $f'(x)$ would have at least $3$ distinct real roots. But it does not.

It follows that $f(x)$ cannot have all roots real. Thus it has at least one complex non-real root, and therefore at least two. It follows that there are two real roots and two complex non-real roots.

Comment: This line I can't comprehend : " The author has shown that if there are only real roots, then these roots must be distinct. "  :/ . Why do they need to be distinct. ?

Comment: For the argument, we need them to be distinct so we can conclude the derivative has at least $3$ distinct roots, the ones described in my answer, in the interval from $a$ to $b$ and so on. We **verify** the roots are distinct by noting that a double root is also a root of the derivative. The roots of the derivative are easy to find. By plugging in we can see they are not roots of $f(x)$ so $f(x)$ cannot have any double roots.